# My WordPress site made using softaculous stopped working after moving files out to root folder

Tags: plugins

I have an existing HTML website on domain name Tarkarlinext.com. In cpanel file manager, I have html files in public_html folder and site continues to run.

One day, I installed WordPress script through softaculous app installer in a folder in public_html. I named that folder WP. so my new website's url became Tarkarlinext.com/wp. I did my work through tarkarlinext.com/wp/admin and decided to move my new WordPress website to main domain for testing purpose. Intention was to move my WordPress site from Tarkarlinext.com/wp to Tarkarlinext.com.

For that, I moved files inside WP folder to Public_html folder (one level up).

I made two mistakes. 1. I did not backup in wordpress app. 2. Instead of copying files I **moved** them.

Expected result was not achieved and I tried putting files back in WP folder. But WordPress site did not run and gave me error message error establishing connection to database.

Please help me with this.

Comment: Hey, Just copy pasting the content will not work. wordpress information are linked to database..so you have to make changes to database as well ( update the url etc)...best solution will be install a fresh wordpress copy in the main domain and use plugin like All-in-One WP Migration for migration ..yes you have messed up :)

Answer (score 0):

Wordpress Migration will not work just my moving the WordPress files.

[More info in this link](https://codex.wordpress.org/Moving_WordPress)

If you have removed the database then it's not possible to bring back `tarkarlinext.com/wp/`

---

- Create a folder named `wp` inside public_html folder
- Move every thing inside public_html folder to `wp` folder

This should make `tarkarlinext.com/wp/` to work

---

For migration you may go for plugin like All-in-One.